# Change font and Colours in Menus

Tags: title, sub-menu, text, fonts

I am new to WP and hoping to get some help.
I am well on the way to building my new website, but have some small detail issues.
I would like to change the font, size and colour of my Menu titles, and also the same for my dropdown menus. I attach a scren shot.
I would like to change the colour to the BLUE in my name - it is #48a1d9, and also the font to garamond , which is my logo font.
I heard I need to change or add some css settings, but do not know how to do this or where to find these.
Can anyone help me, I would be most grateful,
Regards,
Eamonn Nolan
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Goto your dashboard > appearance > customize there you can find some options to change button color,font size etc.

To target your ul in menu you need to use below class:

```
ul.nav-menu
```

To target the li a of your menu use below class :

```
.menu ul.nav-menu li a
```

To target you ul under the parent ul you need to use below class :

```
ul.sub-menu
```

Target li a of your sub menu :

```
ul.sub-menu li a
```

Hope now you can do it by your self.

Comment: Is it working well? if yes than give the rating so other can use it for reference.

Comment: Thanks but no, I do not see where to change fonts, colours etc.

Comment: Sorry, I sent that before I was finished. Just saying, sorry but I am new to all this and only learning. When I go dashboard >appearnace>customize this is where I am, and not sure where to change it . Have screen shot but will not load.    Down right hand of screen is Front Page Header,Site Identity,Background colour, backgrouind image, Menus, widgets, static front page, additional CCS, post options.     Cannot see where to change fonts and colours. regards, Eamonn

Comment: It may be possible your theme is not having the options of font size.

Comment: Target the class as i given to you and write css in style.css file.  Sorry to ask you but are you a developer?

Comment: No, I am a small private individual trying to set up this website. Thanks.

Comment: Than you need a developer because it is hard for non technical person to set the values in the files.

Comment: Ok,   I have done a lot of the work on this , but I would like it finished correclty. Is this the type of work you do, if I gave you access , can you finish it for me. What might that cost. I have the layout ok, I have the pages set up - HOME, ABOUT, SERVICES .I do not have the CONTACT page set up. I have 3 of the four sub pages set up and I can set the 4th one up, I just dont have the text ready yet. So really it is just the finishing to get it really right. What can you do for me .Regards and thanks fr your help so far,